# Sockets or using wso2 for receiving and processing data in realtime

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, websocket, wso2

I would like to know if it is possible, and that the approach I am using is right :)

I am on .net with c# and DB being SQL.

I am trying to create an application, wherein I would be getting multiple data  (a benchmark of 1000 records, per second), we are talking of each record of roughly half a kb.

I need to receive the same, process data to trigger notifications, and then insert into database.

My solution:
(a) Receiving Data on Load Balancer.
(b) use some kind of technique with Sockets to receive data on various ports on each server.
(c) Store intermediately (this I have to yet to figure out) because I would need to process each packet, for right notification (notifications are update on the webpage at client site)
(d) I would then insert the data into database.

I would need to have some suggestion, the right path, i will figure out the code in due course, but need a direction on the approach and technology.

I was also told that if I use wso2 middleware, I could achieve the above without investing in heavy servers

Answer (score 0):

Use WSO2 BAM. It is built to do exactly what you have asked to do and is open source. Download it and run couple of samples. Download the [binary and docs](http://wso2.com/products/business-activity-monitor). It has a very fast Java SDK to publish custom data. There is also a REST API for the same purpose. This would interest you since you are using C#.

Answer (score 0):

The database IO will be your bottleneck depending on what you use for a setup.

As far as the C# socket app goes, if you use asynchronous sockets, 1000 packets per second is not a whole lot and you should not need a load balancer. As you are getting the packets, handle them and store the data in C# intermediary class objects that you can perform logic in to determine if the website requires updating. These classes will also handle inserting the records into the database and signaling the website that you have new data. I use SignalR to do this from a C# application to an asp.net web application.